# D3 Multi-Layer Timeline

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This gets a little complicated, but I'm trying to create a timeline graph, similar to the one shown here:

http://bl.ocks.org/bunkat/2338034

The hiccup comes in with my data. I've got 3 different feeds that take data from 7 different sensors. Some sensors may send a response at the same time as other sensors, so the overlaps are causing some issues with my current code.

essentially, I want to show something like this: 
[image]

my data looks something like this:

```
[
  {
    "ID": "run0001",
    "data": [
        {"Time": 760 , "EndTime": 780,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 780 , "EndTime": 800 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 780 , "EndTime": 800 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorD", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-1" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":0},
        {"Time": 760 , "EndTime": 780 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 780 , "EndTime": 800 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 780 , "EndTime": 800 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorB", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-2" , "FeedName": "SensorA", "lane":1},
        {"Time": 760 , "EndTime": 780 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorC", "lane":2},
        {"Time": 780 , "EndTime": 800 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorC", "lane":2},
        {"Time": 780 , "EndTime": 800 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorC", "lane":2},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorF", "lane":2},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorF", "lane":2},
        {"Time": 800 , "EndTime": 820 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorF", "lane":2},
        {"Time": 820 , "EndTime": 840 ,  "Feed": "Feed-3" , "FeedName": "SensorG", "lane":2}

    ]
  }
]
```

Any thoughts on how I would handle this?

Comment: So apart from your timeline example, the real question is how to merge those two arrays into one? Or am I missing something? It appears that the combination of `Feed`, `FeedName`, and `lane` fields make a unique "key" -- take a look at using the `d3.nest` function to combine them, and aggregate any overlapping time ranges...

Comment: I updated my original post so it wasn't as confusing (ignore the second portion of the JSON that was there previously). I think you're right that I will need to use d3.nest, but my real question is: 

how do I create a timeline "row" and ensure that the data blocks do not overlap (as in the picture, marked by 'Sensor')

when I originally tried this, the overall look was glitchy blocks were not appearing on the timeline as expected

Comment: What attempt did you make to have d3 draw the subsets in the timeline?

Comment: Are you needing to roll-your-own functions? If not, there are some canned libraries out there, like google Timelines:  https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/timeline
 or this npm module:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/timelines-chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just so this is marked as answered -- all the credit goes to @SteveR for finding the npm module npmjs.com/package/timelines-chart  which does exactly what I need. Thank you!

[github - timelines-chart](https://github.com/vasturiano/timelines-chart)